# Hibernate reactive sesion factory intialization error in a Vertx/Spring integration application

Tags: spring, vert.x, hibernate-reactive

I created a simple Spring/Vertx integration example application and add Hibernate Reactive to replace the existing Postgres Reactive Client API.

Source codes: https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/blob/master/mutiny-spring-hibernate

When running the application and I try to access http://localhost:8888/posts,  it is blocked and return nothing, in the background console, the sql is printed.

When I ran the testing codes, it throws an exception, the `PostRepository` constructor  0 `SessionFactory` bean is not run on the vertx event loop.

```java
@Bean
public Mutiny.SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("blogPU")
        .unwrap(Mutiny.SessionFactory.class);
}
```

**Updated:**, when I changed my handler codes to the following.

```java
this.posts.findAll()
.subscribe()
.with(
    data -> {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "posts data: {0}", data);
        rc.response().endAndAwait(Json.encode(data));
    },
    rc::fail
);
```

Here, use `endAndAwait` instead of the original `end` method, it works.

But the test method still failed, due to an empty list returned when accessing the endpoint `/posts`.

When I explored the official howto guides: https://github.com/vertx-howtos/hibernate-reactive-howto, which created the `SessionFactory` in the `Verticle` class to ensure they are run on the same thread.

Comment: Your tests are green for me and the endpoint returns an array with two items

Comment: @Selim on my machine, it returns an empty array when testing the `/posts` endpoint.